# How I can send a value to a thread instead the reference

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm creating a thread in C but it passes the reference instead the value.

```
  for (i=0; i<num_thread; i++){
  pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, mou_oponent,(void *)&i);
}

int mou_oponent(void* ind) //THIS IS THE HEADER OF THE FUNCTION
```

I need the value not the reference, because I take the value of i in the thread but it is changed because the for increments it.

Answer (score 0):

in `int mou_oponent(void* ind)` you should copy to other memory by other variable, then you work on other variable instead `ind`.
hope it's help